# Creating dynamic text URL rewrites to IDs - best practice?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a site where there are a number of articles stored in a database with their respective IDs. Each of these articles will have a SEO friendly text URL, which is then processed by PHP/.htaccess to fetch the matching article by its ID. What would be the best practice for accomplishing this?

For example, let's say I have this URL: `www.mysite.com/articles/hello-world/`. And it should take me to an article that has an ID of 4.

My best guess is I should add a column in the DB table that has that text string (added upon publishing the article).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is the best practice. I can't imagine any others

Answer (score 1):

I am currently reading about Symfony and they have solved this "problem" adding a new column named 'slug' to the database, but anyway they show the ID in the url.

In [this link](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05) they explain this, and show practices examples.

PS: Sorry my bad english.

Comment: I think you're not bad in English at all, and I think that just your "PS" is wrong :D

Comment: I haven't looked into the WordPress engine but I figure it works pretty much the same, especially as the user can set his/her own URL text/slug when publishing. Will go with this method.

Comment: Hah thanks @genesis; Staffan, i think the "magic" is in the .htaccess file.

Comment: FxckDead: Yes, for static/dynamic ID rewrites .htaccess is enough. But dynamic text rewrites is something else...